# cannot update from lubutu 18 to 20 lts version on asus old laptop current version 18.04.5 lts

Tags: lubuntu, asus, lts

```
cannot upgrade to next lts version
not in terminal and not in updater
current version is updated and working
main.log
2021-03-02 10:47:01,638 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.bionic']'
2021-03-02 10:47:01,639 INFO uname information: 'Linux asus-1225B 4.15.0-136-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 28 05:20:47 UTC 2021 x86_64'
2021-03-02 10:47:03,335 INFO apt version: '1.6.12ubuntu0.2'
2021-03-02 10:47:03,336 INFO python version: '3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0]'
2021-03-02 10:47:03,351 INFO release-upgrader version '20.04.29' started
2021-03-02 10:47:03,401 INFO locale: 'nl_NL' 'UTF-8'
2021-03-02 10:47:03,663 INFO screen could not be run
2021-03-02 10:47:03,811 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2021-03-02 10:47:04,056 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2021-03-02 10:47:04,196 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2021-03-02 10:47:24,126 DEBUG lsb-release: 'bionic'
2021-03-02 10:47:24,132 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2021-03-02 10:47:24,135 DEBUG openCache()
2021-03-02 10:47:24,136 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2021-03-02 10:47:24,136 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2021-03-02 10:47:31,013 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-128 with 
2021-03-02 10:47:31,016 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-136 with 4.15.0-128
2021-03-02 10:47:33,428 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 102068
2021-03-02 10:47:33,431 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of key deps for 'lubuntu-desktop')
2021-03-02 10:47:33,431 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2021-03-02 10:47:33,439 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2021-03-02 10:47:38,964 DEBUG openCache()
2021-03-02 10:47:45,826 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-128 with 
2021-03-02 10:47:45,829 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-136 with 4.15.0-128
2021-03-02 10:47:48,245 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 102068
2021-03-02 10:47:48,246 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2021-03-02 10:47:48,246 DEBUG quirks: running focalPostInitialUpdate
2021-03-02 10:47:48,247 DEBUG running Quirks.focalPostInitialUpdate
2021-03-02 10:48:15,322 DEBUG MetaPkgs: 
2021-03-02 10:48:36,646 DEBUG Foreign: 
2021-03-02 10:48:36,647 DEBUG Obsolete: google-chrome-stable
2021-03-02 10:48:36,648 DEBUG updateSourcesList()
2021-03-02 10:48:36,713 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList() with mirror_check
2021-03-02 10:48:36,714 DEBUG ['ubuntu-minimal', 'ubuntu-standard']
2021-03-02 10:48:36,714 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-minimal
2021-03-02 10:48:36,726 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-standard
2021-03-02 10:48:36,739 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted'
2021-03-02 10:48:36,740 DEBUG verifySourcesListEntry: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted2021-03-02 10:48:38,056 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2021-03-02 10:49:49,653 DEBUG openCache()
2021-03-02 10:49:54,600 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-128 with 
2021-03-02 10:49:54,601 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-136 with 4.15.0-128
2021-03-02 10:49:56,178 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 67833
2021-03-02 10:49:56,181 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of key deps for 'lubuntu-desktop')
2021-03-02 10:49:56,183 DEBUG quirks: running PreDistUpgradeCache
2021-03-02 10:49:56,184 DEBUG running Quirks.PreDistUpgradeCache
2021-03-02 10:49:56,184 INFO checking for python-dbg
2021-03-02 10:49:56,185 INFO checking for python-doc
2021-03-02 10:49:56,185 INFO checking for python-minimal
2021-03-02 10:49:56,185 INFO installing python-is-python2 because python-minimal was installed
2021-03-02 10:49:56,186 DEBUG Installing 'python-is-python2' (python-minimal was installed on the system)
2021-03-02 10:49:56,312 INFO removing python-minimal because python-is-python2 is being installed
2021-03-02 10:49:56,314 DEBUG Removing 'python-minimal' (python-is-python2 is being installed on the system)
2021-03-02 10:49:56,315 INFO failed to remove python-minimal
2021-03-02 10:49:56,317 INFO checking for python-dev
2021-03-02 10:49:56,318 INFO checking for libpython-dev
2021-03-02 10:49:56,319 INFO checking for libpython-stdlib
2021-03-02 10:49:56,319 INFO removing libpython-stdlib because None is being installed
2021-03-02 10:49:56,320 DEBUG Removing 'libpython-stdlib' (None is being installed on the system)
2021-03-02 10:49:56,320 INFO failed to remove libpython-stdlib
2021-03-02 10:49:56,320 INFO checking for libpython-dbg
2021-03-02 10:49:58,040 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Fout, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve leverde defecten op. Dit kan veroorzaakt worden door vastgehouden pakketten.'
2021-03-02 10:49:58,042 DEBUG abort called
2021-03-02 10:49:58,046 DEBUG openCache()
2021-03-02 10:50:13,409 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-128 with 
2021-03-02 10:50:13,412 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-136 with 4.15.0-128
2021-03-02 10:50:15,877 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 102068
```

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last release with LXDE, and the release notes for 20.04 (https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/) state clearly "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*" so I'd suggest not upgrading anyway.

Comment: Also note Lubuntu is a desktop release, so it's releases use the format *year.month* such as the 18.04 LTS you mention.  Ubuntu also has specialist releases using the *year* format, such as Ubuntu Core 18, they however are *snap* only and do not contain a desktop by default. Lubuntu has not produced any *snap* only releases, and neither LXDE or LXQt have been packaged as *snaps* for use in specialist releases such as Ubuntu Core 18, or Ubuntu Core 20.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of upgrading from lubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 is to back up your data, and do a clean install. Lubuntu doesn't recommend using the upgrade function (and I think they made sure it cant upgrade from 18.04) to go to the new desktop enviroment. (And if you don't like the new desktop enviroment, you can use another distro like Kubuntu and use the same backup to recover your data.)

Comment: thank you for answers